# interrupt C timers

Tags: c, timer, interrupt

There seems to be a conflict between timer 2 and timer 3. This is a MIPS board and instead of using assembly language to program; I am using C. Timer1 is for a count which works properly. Timer2 is for a blinking LED which works properly. Timer3 is for switching count directions. But there is a conflict between timer2 and timer3. Does anyone know where the conflict is? I have to comment out DelayInit3(); in order for the code to execute properly.

```
void __ISR(_TIMER_2_VECTOR, ipl2) Timer2Handler(void)
{
// clear the interrupt flag
mT2ClearIntFlag();
    PORTToggleBits(IOPORT_B, BIT_10); 
 }
 void __ISR(_TIMER_23_VECTOR, ipl2) Timer23Handler(void)
 {
    // clear the interrupt flag
    mT3ClearIntFlag();
    if (direction != 0){
        direction < 1;
    }
    else{
        direction != 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
DeviceInit();
DelayInit1();
DelayInit2();
//  DelayInit3();

}
void DelayInit1()   
{
unsigned int tcfg1;

/* Configure Timer 1. This sets it up to count a 10Mhz with a period of 0xFFFF
  */
    tcfg1 =     T1_ON|T1_IDLE_CON|T1_SOURCE_INT|T1_PS_1_8|T1_GATE_OFF|T1_SYNC_EXT_OFF;
OpenTimer1(tcfg1, 0xFFFF);

}


void DelayInit2()
{
unsigned int tcfg2;

// Config Timer 2. This sets it to count 312500 Hz with a period of T2_TICK
tcfg2 = T2_ON | T2_SOURCE_INT | T2_PS_1_32;
OpenTimer2(tcfg2, T2_TICK);

// Now enable system-wide multi-vector interrupt handling
INTEnableSystemMultiVectoredInt();

// Configure timer 2 interrupt with a priority of 2
ConfigIntTimer2(T2_INT_ON | T2_INT_PRIOR_2);

// Clear interrupt flag
mT2ClearIntFlag();
}

void DelayInit3()
{
unsigned int tcfg3;

// Config Timer 3. This sets it to count 312500 Hz with a period of T3_TICK
tcfg3 = T3_ON | T3_SOURCE_INT | T3_PS_1_256;
OpenTimer23(tcfg3, T23_TICK);

// Now enable system-wide multi-vector interrupt handling
INTEnableSystemMultiVectoredInt();

// Configure timer 3 interrupt with a priority of 2
ConfigIntTimer23(T23_INT_ON | T23_INT_PRIOR_2);

// Clear interrupt flag
mT3ClearIntFlag();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also toggle the bits at every timer end. The order that you are toggling is wrong. At every timer finish, you are toggling BIT10 twice, i.e. getting it back to initial position.

You can use code like this.

```
count = 0;  // in Init.
while(1)
{
    if (IFS0bits.T2IF == 1)
    {
        //if timer == period, toggle the LED
        count++;
        PORTToggleBits(IOPORT_B, BIT_10);
        if (count %2 == 0)
        {
          DelayMs(2);
          PORTToggleBits(IOPORT_B, BIT_11);
        }
        if (count > 3)
           count = 0;
        mT2ClearIntFlag();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are toggleing the Bit 10 with a delay of 2 ms to it's first state. Even if this works, you will not notice.